# Strange single quotation on folder name inside home folder after installing homebrew

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, homebrew, nvm

I am not quite sure what happen to my home folder, but it just appear a " ' " single quotation mark on that folder name which is quite annoying.

I installed sass and grunt on my computer and for everything to works I need to install homebrew, rvm, and nvm.

I am no expert into these and not sure what it does.

Mind anyone to help me if this is safe to remove or should I rename it into other names instead?

Thank you!

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: It looks like you simply accidentally created a new folder with that name, and directed the files to go there.  It should be safe to rename it.  It is unlikely that you have purposefully configured anything that would rely upon the contents to look there.

Comment: From the contents of that folder, it looks like Homebrew got installed into it; maybe Sass or Grunt installed Homebrew automatically, but there's a bug in the installer that put it there?. I think you can delete it and try reinstalling Homebrew in /usr/local.